# How to read input several lines of integers seperated by spaces (in C++)?

Tags: c++, atoi

So there are Q lines.
Each line has an arbitrary number of integers separated by spaces, I need to process those numbers.

*Example Input*

```
Q = 4
12 32 4 3 2
1 2 3 4 
0
2 3 1 223 4 2 3
```

I am reading each line as string and extracting the numbers as string and then using atoi to convert them to int, ie,

```
while(Q>0){
        for(char c:s){
            if (c==' '){
                int x = atoi(temp.c_str());
                temp = "";
                //process x
                continue;
            }
            temp +=c;
        }
        Q--;
    }
```

Surely there is a better way to do this?

Edit: The numbers of each line are processed differently.

For example, say

Line 1 has 1,2,3,4. Line 2 has 14,15.

Then 1,2,3,4 will be processed differently and 13,14 differently.

This is why I can't use std::cin as it ignores all whitespaces (both spaces and newline).

Comment: I'd just read each line and parse using regex.

Comment: @RyanPierceWilliams could you please elaborate how to do that?

Comment: You could use a regex like this on each line: "([\d]+)" to find all integers.

Comment: Try it out here: https://regex101.com/

Comment: Is there a pattern on how you process them differently?

Comment: You'll need to study up on regex. When you place things in parentheses you are creating a group. You can use the results from searching/matching with such a regex to grab the parsed groups. In this case, each group is an individual integer string from the line being evaluated.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>

// ...

int x;
while (std::cin >> x)
    ; // process x
```

---

edited cause of your comment:

```
#include <iostream>

// ...

int x;
char ch;
while (std::cin >> x >> std::noskipws >> ch >> std::skipws) {
    if (ch == '\n')
        ; // process x differently
}
```

Comment: cin ignores all whitespaces by default.
I need to separately process integers belonging to each line.
Example 
line 1: 1 2 3 4  line 2: 12 34

Here 1,2,3,4 will be processed differently and 12,34 differently.

Comment: Sorry fixed it now.

Answer (score 0):

If you need line oriented parsing and still want to use the power of iostream then I suggest you use `std::getline` and `std::istringstream`. Example below

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main() {
    char ch = '\0';
    std::cin >> ch;
    if (!std::cin || ch != 'Q') return EXIT_FAILURE;
    std::cin >> ch;
    if (!std::cin || ch != '=') return EXIT_FAILURE;
    int Q = 0;
    std::cin >> Q;
    if (!std::cin) return EXIT_FAILURE;
    std::string line;
    std::getline(std::cin, line); // get ready for a new line
    while (Q > 0) {
        if (!std::getline(std::cin, line)) return EXIT_FAILURE;
        std::istringstream iss(line);
        int count = 0;
        int sum = 0;
        int i;
        while (iss >> i) {
            ++count;
            sum += i;
        }
        std::cout << "Found " << count << " integers who's sum was " << sum << '\n';
        Q--;
    }
    std::cout << "Done\n";
}
```